# React component ui issues with props

Tags: react-redux

I have something like this

```
{
 !this.props.ifYes && <Redirect component = {No}/>
}
{
 this.props.ifYes && <Redirect component = {Yes} />
}
```

So even when ifYes is true, it will redirect to the No component first for like quarter of a second ,and then redirect again to Yes component after it recieved its props from redux.

Which react life cycle should I manipulate?

Comment: `this.props.ifYes ? <Redirect component = {Yes}/> : <Redirect component = {No}/>`

Comment: Thanks, I feel so dumb haha.

Comment: Glad to help @John

Comment: @Hackerman, It does the same thing, since before the component recieve its props, it will be false so redirect to the first one, then after it recieved its prosp, it will become true.

Comment: What if the redirect does not exist in the Switch until the component recieve its props. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Redirect component = {this.props.ifYes ? Yes : No}/>
```

Comment: Isnt it the same? Since it will be false when the page just refresh because it didnt reciEve its props yet.So it will go to No, and then Yes after it recieved its props.